# Errors: No column name was specified for column 2 of 'Qry'

Tags: marketing-cloud, soql, query

I try to extract email duplicates from All Subscriber list of Marketing Cloud and I have a syntax error that I do not understand.

```
select 

a.EmailAddress,
COUNT(a.EmailAddress)

from _ListSubscribers a

GROUP BY a.EmailAddress
HAVING COUNT(a.EmailAddress)>1
```

Error : No column name was specified for column 2 of 'Qry'.

Thanks in advance,
Anne-Sophie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to use a function like COUNT(), you need to follow it up with a resulting fieldname, in which the result should be returned. This column of course needs to exist in your target DE. In this example, it's called "mycount":

```
select 

a.EmailAddress,
COUNT(a.EmailAddress) AS myCount

from _ListSubscribers a

GROUP BY a.EmailAddress
HAVING COUNT(a.EmailAddress)>1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working :))) you are the best Jonas !

Comment: @Anne-Sophie, you can mark your question as answered, if you like.